# How to preserve a 'rich text' field property when updating a MS Access table

Tags: ms-access, import, formatting, richtext

When I update my MS Access table using "Saved imports" feature, the updated table preserves the data type ('Long text') but does not preserve the field property (Text Format: 'Rich text'). The 'Rich text' field property down in the table design mode switches back to 'Plain text' after every update import.

Is there a way to preserve the Rich text field property?

I have spent hours on various forums but weren't successful. Using plain text and HTML commands like line break ect. is not an option in this case.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Any reason why you cannot import into an empty existing table? This is also good for avoiding bloat.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, only the memo field type will save rich text tags in their proper formats.

Comment: Thanks for your responses...

Comment: I am updating this table regularly, so I can't use an empty one.

How to set a Memo field type - I don't see it in the dropdown list?

Alternatively, I have been trying to code a VBA - something like CurrentDB.TableDefs("table1").Fields("field1")....property.("rich text") but without any success.

Would this be a way to go?

Thanks!

Comment: After hours and hours was the solution easy my dear Watson...
-Delete the records in the original table and append from the Excel file. This preserves the Rich text formatting.

Comment: I didn't realize you meant the append function. I didn't know about this Import option :) Thank you!

Comment: I tried Appending to existing table, using a Memo field set to Rich Text - the import did NOT preserve the RTF in Excel. :(  Have I missed something?